# Normalizing Data Before Predictive Modeling

Tags: normalization

I have two questions regarding the normalization of data prior a predictive modeling.

1) When do I need to normalize the data and when not ? I know that for KNN models for example, one always have to normalize, but we don't always do it for linear regression for example, how do you know ?

2) Normalization has to come BEFORE splitting the data so the testing set doesn't get contaminated. However, in order to predict, I will need to normalize the testing set after the modeling, prior the predictions. How do I normalize it, using the mean/sd of training set or testing set, and why ?

Thank you !

Comment: Normalizing/standardization before splitting _is_ leaking information from the train set to the test set.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. So technically how would you do it ? You normalize the training set only, get coefficients (in regression for example), and then what ? If you want predictions, you will need to normalize the testing set before prediction. Should I use the mean / std of the testing set or training set ?

Comment: You point 2 reads as normalizing the whole data set before splitting. Using the mean and standard deviation is called standardization. You normalize something to fit in a particular range (like $(0,1)$). The correct way is to standardize (if that is what you mean) the train set, save the train means and SDs, then use those again to standardize the test set. As an aside, I wanted to mark your (2) as duplicate, because there is already a nice answer to it, which is why we discourage asking multiple questions in one post. In addition, I think (1) is a bit too broad to answer on a Q&A.

Comment: (Continued) In general though, you standardize or normalize whenever that increases numerical stability, or you have some requirement like $0$ mean, such as in ridge regression. If that answer your questions satisfactorily, I'll convert my comments to an answer.